# Objective-C: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xba3e750

Tags: ios, exception

I have written this code and when I run the program it throws exception: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xba3e750

```
 storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewID"];
    selected = navigationController.viewControllers[0];
```

when I put this line in comment

```
//selected = navigationController.viewControllers[0];
```

like that , the program doesn't throw exception.
this is whole exception

> 2014-06-12 20:59:44.749 passing image[2194:a0b] -[SecondViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xba3e750
>   2014-06-12 20:59:44.753 passing image[2194:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SecondViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xba3e750'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x017445e4 **exceptionPreprocess + 180
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014c78b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x017e1903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x0173490b ___forwarding_** + 1019
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x017344ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
>       5   passing image                       0x000056a2 -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 466
>       6   UIKit                               0x00349318 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
>       7   UIKit                               0x003495b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
>       8   UIKit                               0x002719fd -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
>       9   UIKit                               0x00271d97 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
>       10  UIKit                               0x0027202d -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
>       11  UIKit                               0x0027c89a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
>       12  UIKit                               0x0022fcd0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1851
>       13  UIKit                               0x002343a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
>       14  UIKit                               0x0024887c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
>       15  UIKit                               0x00248de9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
>       16  UIKit                               0x00236025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
>       17  GraphicsServices                    0x037932f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
>       18  GraphicsServices                    0x03792e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x016bfd65 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 53
>       20  CoreFoundation                      0x016bfa9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
>       21  CoreFoundation                      0x016ea77c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
>       22  CoreFoundation                      0x016e9ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
>       23  CoreFoundation                      0x016e98db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
>       24  UIKit                               0x00233add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
>       25  UIKit                               0x00235d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
>       26  passing image                       0x0000750d main + 141
>       27  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e78725 start + 0
>       28  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Comment: can you please add the whole error message from console.

Comment: it seems, that your ViewController "SecondViewController" isn't a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: property UIStoryboard *storyboard;
property UINavigationController *navigationController;
property SecondViewController *selected;

Comment: @Caleb sorry, i meant `UINavigationController` of course. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` returns a `UIViewController`, but you're storing it in a `UINavigationController` when you shouldn't. When you try to access a `UINavigationController` property (`viewControllers`), it crashed because `UIViewController` doesn't have a property named `viewControllers`.

Try storing the return of the method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` in a `UIViewController` instead of a `UINavigationController` :

```
UIViewController * viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewID"];
selected = viewController.navigationController.viewControllers[0];
```

Comment: +1 There's no actual cast happening, but you're right that the OP is sending a `UINavigationController` message to a view controller that's not a nav controller.

Comment: no exception but the program don't work properly . There is a button when I click it that will go to a new view controller (selected)but in that controller there are no navigation buttons at the top of the screen.